# removeAction/removeViewAction vs removedJobAction/removedViewAction

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

The Jenkins Job DSL Plugin documentation describes the following:

- [`removeAction`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.DslContext.removeAction) - "action to be taken for job that have been removed from DSL scripts"
- [`removeViewAction`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.DslContext.removeViewAction) - "action to be taken for views that have been removed from DSL scripts"

However the [pipeline documentation for Job DSL](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/job-dsl/) lists slightly different names:

- `removedJobAction` (extra `d` and `Job`)
- `removedViewAction` (extra `d`)

They seem to have the same effect so why are there 2 subtly different spellings for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Having resorted to the `job-dsl-plugin` source code ([here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/job-dsl-1.77/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/helpers/step/DslContext.groovy#L55-L76)) it turns out the shorter names (listed first above) are basically pass-through methods to their longer-named counterparts, but with extra checks on the values passed to ensure they are in the expected list of actions.

So you can use either, but `removeAction` and `removeViewAction` will throw helpful errors if you pass an invalid string.

Comment: Actually the ones which start `removed` may only work under a `jobDsl` section whereas those starting `remove` (without the `d`) may only work under a `dsl` section (I haven't actually tried this...)